# How to compare nested array from collection and pure array?

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections

Need to update the post with tags after comparing two arrays. How to extract the 'id' of nested array in a new array?

```
<pre>
//$post->tags->toArray() 
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "tag1"
    "created_at" => "2020-07-27T17:36:28.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2020-07-27T17:36:28.000000Z"
    "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "tag2"
    "created_at" => "2020-07-27T17:36:30.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2020-07-27T17:36:30.000000Z"
    "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
  ]
]

//Result of $request->tags
array:3 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "3"
]

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it correctly,

```
$tags = array();
foreach($posts as $p)
{
    array_push($tags, $p['id']);
}
```

[image: Code Review]